# Password reset on user_save() issue

Tags: 7, users

I used user_save to update the field. 
However, whenever I run this function and I log out and try to log back the password doesn't work anymore.I think it cause a change in the password. can anyone help me to get the actual password back?

```
$existingUser1 = user_load($uid1);
$existingUser1->field_group_id[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $g_id;
user_save((object) array('uid' => $existingUser1->uid), (array) $existingUser1);
```

Comment: Just for clarification, why do you need your old password?
Have you forgotten your new password or you are not aware that with what password it has got saved?

Comment: I updated one field of all the users using user_save, coz of which password of each-one is changed automatically so to access the system every user will need to-reset the password.Its like we are forcing user to reset the password.

Comment: Need to see your code before we can give any kind of effective answer.

Comment: @Jaypan i added the code.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want this:

```
$existingUser1 = user_load($uid1);
$existingUser1->field_group_id[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $g_id;
user_save($existingUser1);
```

You just need to call user_save() on the user object to save the values after you have changed any fields.

Comment: Hey Jaypan, could you please add some explanation for the code you posted. Not doing so is considered as a low quaity post according the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) (oeps: rules) of this site ... and puts it at risk of beiing deleted via moderation (FYI: your answer did show up in the low quality posts ...). Just a suggestion ...

Comment: There wasn't much to say, but I added some more.

Comment: That's what experts often say ... but your improvement helps for sure. And if you ask me "good enough". So merci for taking my advice ... PS: it also makes your answer "more effective" (as in your own comments to the question ...)

Comment: @Jaypan the solution provided by you works well.But is there any solution for the problem caused by the previous code?

Comment: Pierre - fair enough, I guess after writing code for so long it's easy to forget that it's not always clear to other people what exactly is happening.

Comment: Brrocks - I'm guessing that the password isn't part of the user object or is empty, so when you converted the user object to an array in the second argument to `user_save()`, the system saves the values, but the password is empty, so your password is overwritten with an empty password.